# Accessing Hapi request id without passing the request object everywhere?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have a REST API written in Node.js/Hapi and I'm working on adding logging to it and integrating that to a centralized logging service like Splunk.

What I'd like to be able to do is write a simple logging util so that anywhere in the code I can do something like:

`LoggingUtil.log('some message');`

and the LoggingUtil would be able to figure out which request it pertains to and include that in the actual message that gets logged. That way when I search the logs the request id will tie together all the logs pertaining to a specific request.

I'm not super familiar with the event loop in Node and how I could accomplish this. The only thing I've found that might work is [tick-id](https://github.com/watson/tick-id)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I give 2 suggestions based on whether you want logging all the time or just for debugging.

1. logging all the time example using Hapi's lifecycle method

   ```
   server.ext('onRequest', (request, reply) => {
   console.log(`\n++++++  ${request.raw.req.method} ${request.raw.req.url} ++++++\n`);
   reply.continue();
   });
   ```

onRequest means every time there is a request, this function is called. for mine I made it log the request method and URL. you can observe the request object to get the info you want.

2. logging only for debugging

basically same logic, pass the request object and access the info you need from there.

In your log function:
    `log(request) {
    console.log(WHATEVER_YOU_NEED)
}`